# Hide Rows onEdit in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script triggered by a yes/no field in B2 to hide all rows in Budget_01 sheet wherever 0 is found in column B. For example in table Budget_01:

BUDGET_01 TABLE WITH HIDE ZERO [B2]= "No" All rows unhidden

```
Budget_01
Hide Zero|No
Expense  | Amount | Frequency
Car loan  500.00   1
Gas       0        0
Music     0        1
Supplies  50       20
....
Books     0        0
```

BUDGET_01 TABLE WITH HIDE ZERO [B2]= "Yes" All rows where column B = $0 hidden

```
Budget_01
Hide Zero|Yes
Expense  | Amount | Frequency
Car loan  500.00   1
Supplies  50       20
```

This is my attempt that does not work:

```
    function toggleRows() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Budget 01");  
    var cellValue = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();

      if(cellValue == 'No'){
          for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            // get sheet
            var sh = sheets[i];

            // unhide rows
            var rRows = sh.getRange("A1:A");
            sh.unhideRow(rRows);
          }

        }

        if(cellValue == 'Yes'){
            ss.showRows(1, ss.getMaxRows());
            ss.getRange('B1:B')
                .getValues()
            .forEach(function (r, i) {
                if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
                    .charAt(0) == 0) ss.hideRows(i + 1)
            }); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to set up a form trigger in the script editor. Resources > Triggers > add new. Set it to on edit.

Comment: Thanks, I set the trigger up but I am not getting the effect of hiding the rows where column B shows $0.

Comment: Off the bat, you have `var i` set in the loop, but then call `iLen` without defining it anywhere, stopping the loop.

Comment: Please add the execution transcript. Reference [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use the yes/no drop down to launch the script I inserted two graphic buttons (insert > drawing square button) marked with yes and no.  I launched these two functions from each button:

```
function hide01Rows() {
  // set up spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    // get sheet
    var sh = sheets[i];

    sh.showRows(1, sh.getMaxRows());
    sh.getRange('B:B')
        .getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
            .charAt(0) == 0) sh.hideRows(i + 1)
    });
  }
}

function unhide0Rows() {
  // set up spreadsheet and sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(), sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for(var i = 0, iLen = sheets.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    // get sheet
    var sh = sheets[i];

    // unhide rows
    var rRows = sh.getRange("A:A");
    sh.unhideRow(rRows);
  }
}
```

This is not the most graceful solution but it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the function name of toggleRows() to onEdit(), and change B1 of "No" to "Yes". By this, when spreadsheet was edited, Budget_01--Unhidden becomes Budget_01--Hidden. If my interpretation was wrong, please tell me it.

Comment: Thank you.  I was not very clear. Sorry.  I edited my explanation above.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `forEach`, I used an `else if` statement to loop through the `Yes` condition.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");         // Change for your sheet

  // Check the condition  
  var cellValue = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  // To hide/unhide, you need a range, not the value. Split into to variables.
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // Check the data being returned
  Logger.log(cellValue);
  Logger.log(values);

  // If "No," unhide the entire range.
  if(cellValue == "No" || "no") {
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      Logger.log("Unhide all rows.");
      sheet.unhideRow(range);
    }

  // If "Yes," loop through the data looking for 0's and hide the range.
  } else if (cellValue == "Yes" || "yes") {
    for(var i=0; i<values.length;i++) {
      if(values[i][1] == 0) {
        Logger.log("Found 0 at row " + i);
        sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(i+1,1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```